# Turtle Beach Headphones audible feedback

Tags: headphones

I have a set of Turtle Beach Earforce X12 headphones and I am getting audible static like noise from them.

I have tried moving the USB connector to a separate machine, and I have altered the volume settings in every conceivable way, but I can't seem to get rid of this static.

Could this be an error with the actual headphones, or is it likely a configuration problem?
Do USB connected headphones suffer from static issues?

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection points, if your power amp box has a disconnect multi pin connection slide it in and out 2 times, then securely connect it.
  The headphone connecting pins could be cleaned with like paper towel which would be slightly abrasive cleaning, then  the jack it is ported into could be cleaned with compressed air can.  Then the connection can be rotated a bit or moved in and out (without overdoing it) to try and improve the connection.

This type of headphone is only powered via the USB, there can be some hiss from the amplification, but static should only exist if connections are not made well or there is a problem with the power supplied or amp curcuit.

The volume of the computer when using any post amplified product like powered headphones, or powered speakers should be put up high.  First lower the volume of the headphones controller so you do not blow your head off.
 Then get all levels in the computer up:
1) for the program itself (programs that have seperate volumes)
2) the seperate app volume controls of the system via the system mixer.
3) the main system volume
4) the level controls in the control pannel sound
would want to be set to 100% or at least somewhat high.

Having a good original signal out of the computer will mean that any noise will be not as noticable, because your not amplyfying noise unnessisarily, because you have a good strong signal comming in to begin with.

If your computer has both front outputs for headphone/speakers and rear outputs also, try both of them , even if that is a difficult reach it would be good to test both. front pannel connections have another connection internal to the motherboard that is not likely to be a problem, but that does add in at least one more connection point.

If using windows 10 and getting static check out "Windows Audio Device Graph Isolation" stop this item and see if the static (temporarily) clears up.

If You cannot get it to function well by general cleaning contacts, and adjusting the many controls in the computer, you may get a good responce from the manufacture in this case  https://www.turtlebeach.com/contact-support